# Microsoft.Http.dll does not exist

Tags: wcf, rest

I need to use the REST feature, HttpMultipartMimeForm, which I believe belongs to Microsoft.Http.dll. But in my .Net 4.0 project I couldn't find it anywhere. I do have my project's Target framework configured as .Net Framework 4, not ..Client Profile, and as an evidence, I do have the System.ServiceModel.Web assembly in the available .net reference list. But I still don't have the Microsoft.Http.dll and therefore, don't have the class I need. I think I may be able to get the dll if I download and install WCF REST Starter Kit but why do I have to do that? .Net 4 is supposed to have it as part of standard, isn't it?

Comment: I believe it's part of the REST starter kit, and that was (essentially) abandoned in favor of WebAPI.

Comment: There's a note on the Codeplex page that says "The WCF REST Starter Kit is no longer supported
To build RESTful services using .NET please use ASP.NET Web API." http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now called MultipartFormDataContent and it is in System.Net.Http.  You can get the nuget from here http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710.0